# scrollview useless showing

Tags: android, scrollview, android-resources

I wrote this code in my android application but it showing warning under scrollview which is "this scrollview or tablerow is possibly useless".
And because of this resource variable 'R' is not getting detected in the java file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/queryEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/queryPrompt"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tagEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/tagPrompt"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/save" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_orange" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taggedSearchesTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/taggedSearches"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/light_orange" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/queryScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/queryTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:stretchColumns="*" >

            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearTagsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="@string/clearTags" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: This shouldn't prevent `R` from being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's shown as (possibly) useless, because you set the height of the TableLayout to "match_parent", which would never give the SrollView anything to actually scroll.

Also, warnings shouldn't prevent the generation of `R` – try cleaning your project ("Project" - Clean…") or "Fix Projekt Properties" (in the project's context menu in the "Android Tools" submenu).

Comment: i changed it to wrap_content even then it is showing possible useless. "R can not be resolved to a varible" is the error which i am getting.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you had a TableRow as top element. Can you post your whole layout? It's hard to guess which part of the layout might be useless. But as I said before: this definitly does not cause the "R can not be resolved to a variable" error – it's just a warning that you could ignore if you like.

Comment: whole layout uploaded plz check

Comment: You should use LinearLayout instead of a TableLayout with TableRows… it's much easier and the way it's intended by Android/Google. I guess that'll make the warnings go away (or at least make it a lot easier to fix).